# Mono for Android: Unknown Runtime after Android update

Tags: xamarin.android

I just received an update from Google for my Galaxy Nexus to Android v4.1.1.

Now when I start debugging with Mono for Android everytime when I start I get this warning:

"Unknown Runtime.

There is a shared runtime on the device whose version cannot be determined.  A new runtime will not be deployed.  If the runtime needs to be replaced, please manually remove it from the device."

And also: "Unknown Platform Runtime

There is a platform support runtime on the device whose version cannot be determined.  A new platform support runtime will not be deployed.  If the platform support runtime needs to be replaced, please manually remove it from the device."

Unfortunately it doesn't tell me HOW to remove that runtime.

Do I have to remove something and if yes, where can I find it on my device?

Comment: I suggest contacting the vendor.

Comment: You should also note that M4A (4.2.4) currently does not support API level 16, it should arrive in 4.2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved with the Mono for Android 4.2.5 (alpha) release.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Mono runtime under the device's list of installed applications, and can uninstall it from there.